# FindViewById in a class type Service?

Tags: java, android

I'm working with the sample media player given by the android sdk. MainActivity starts Service MusicService with `startService(new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PLAY))`.

I need to find a view by ID inside the Service but I don't know how to do it:

```
    findViewById(R.id.playbutton).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I've found some similar questions but none provide a simple solution (the most similar question's accepted answer is actually "no you can't" and I'm sure it's possible). How can I make this line work inside the Service? Do I have to pass the context from MainActivity to it, how do I do it?

Comment: You have no views in a `Service`, so you certainly don't want to do a `findViewBiId` in a `Service`...

Comment: @K-ballo Can services be called using their constructors? I don't recall.

Comment: @A--C: No, no Android managed type does (Activity, Service, Provider, etc). They are created by the system, not you.

Comment: "I need to find a view by ID inside the Service" -- you might wish to take the time to explain this "need" in greater detail. As K-ballo points out, what you want is not realistic. However, since we have no idea what you are really trying to accomplish, nobody can help you with possible alternative solutions.

Comment: the service handles play and pause. It can be initiated from a many different places. I need to make sure that every time the service initiates music the play button is replaced with the pause button and vice versa. Since the service handles media playback the interface should be updated directly before playing/pausing that's why I need to update the ui from it

Comment: [A question made for you][1]. It is for you CommonsWare


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598459/close-was-never-explicitly-called-on-database

Comment: [A question made for you][1]. It is for you CommonsWare


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598459/close-was-never-explicitly-called-on-database

Answer (score 2):

> Since the service handles media playback the interface should be updated directly before playing/pausing that's why I need to update the ui from it

No, you do not. You need to let the UI know, if it exists, about the state change. The UI will affect its own changes how it sees fit. There may not be any UI at all, depending upon what the user has done.

For letting any affected bits of UI know about the state change, you can:

- send a regular broadcast `Intent`, or
- use `LocalBroadcastManager` to send a "narrowcast" `Intent` (works a lot like a broadcast, but it is completely within your process), or
- use [Otto](http://square.github.com/otto/) as an event bus