# Close was never explicitly called on Database

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I have a listview that is sourced by an sqlite db. I call fillData() at several different points to update the listview.

```
private void fillData() {
    readDatabase.open();
    Cursor itemsCursor = readDatabase.fetchAllItems();


    startManagingCursor(itemsCursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseHandler.KEY_ITEM,
            DatabaseHandler.KEY_UNITCOST, DatabaseHandler.KEY_QUANTITY,
            DatabaseHandler.KEY_TOTAL };

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.itemtext, R.id.costtext, R.id.quantitytext,
            R.id.totaltext };

    SimpleCursorAdapter items = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.rowincart, itemsCursor, from, to);

    setListAdapter(items);
    }
```

**Whole code of class is added here**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.cartactivity);
    readDatabase = new DatabaseHandler(this);
//  readDatabase.open();
    loadwidget();
    fillData();
    ListView lv = getListView();
    this.registerForContextMenu(lv);

}

private void loadwidget() {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    cost = extras.getInt("Cost");
    quantity = extras.getInt("quantity");
    product = extras.getString("product");
    Log.i("Hello Testing", cost + " and " + quantity + "   " + product);

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void fillData() {
    readDatabase.open();
    itemsCursor = readDatabase.fetchAllItems();


    startManagingCursor(itemsCursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseHandler.KEY_ITEM,
            DatabaseHandler.KEY_UNITCOST, DatabaseHandler.KEY_QUANTITY,
            DatabaseHandler.KEY_TOTAL };

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.itemtext, R.id.costtext, R.id.quantitytext,
            R.id.totaltext };

    SimpleCursorAdapter items = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.rowincart, itemsCursor, from, to);

    setListAdapter(items);

    }


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    itemsCursor.close();
    readDatabase.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    menu.setHeaderTitle("SMARTAWAY");

    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 1, "Delete Item");

    menu.add(0, UPDATE_ID, 1, "Change Quantity");
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case DELETE_ID:
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        readDatabase.deleteItem(info.id);
        fillData();
        return true;
    case UPDATE_ID:

        final AdapterContextMenuInfo info1 = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Cartactivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        final EditText edit0 = (EditText) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        edit0.setText(String.valueOf(Quantity));
        Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
        dialog.setTitle("          Add More Items          ");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        Button inc = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.inc);
        inc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int c = Integer.parseInt(Quantity);
                c = c + 1;
                Quantity = String.valueOf(c);
                edit0.setText(Quantity);

            }
        });
        Button dec = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dec);
        dec.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int c = Integer.parseInt(Quantity);
                c = c - 1;
                Quantity = String.valueOf(c);
                edit0.setText(Quantity);
            }
        });
        ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                row1 = info1.id; 
                flag = 1;
                int b = Integer.parseInt(Quantity);
                int total = cost * b;
                _total = String.valueOf(total);
                _cost = String.valueOf(cost);
                _quantity = String.valueOf(b);
                _item = product;

                Log.i(row1+" id"+_total +" total"+ _cost +" cost"+ _quantity+" quant", "Hello updated database");

                readDatabase.updateItem(row1, _item, _cost, _quantity, _total);

                fillData();

                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();   
            }
        });
        dialog.show();

        return true;
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long thisID) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, thisID);

    l.showContextMenuForChild(v);

    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Quantity = cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_QUANTITY));
    /*Total = cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_TOTAL));*/

}
```

All the things are going good here, but I found some errors in Logcat ie close() were not called explicitly on database something like this. The error doesnt stop my working anywhere but problem looks wierd. I think I have to close cursor but not sure about that. I have closed database on Destroy but not sure about cursor. Please help.

Same problem is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707713/close-was-never-explicitly-called) but didnt get the actual solution

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: in your activity's `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` just close the database object.  Like, `readDatabase.close()`.

Comment: @user370305 yes I called them but after that I am getting error.

Comment: But before call `close()` on database just make sure its not already closed if not closed then only `close()` the database..

Comment: @user370305 ya database in not closed. already kept in mind while working.

Answer (score 2):

Colse your `cursor` every time after using then your problem will bo solved

```
itemsCursor.close()
```

As you are not closing this, resources of the cursor is not released for that reason when you close your db you are getting that error.

Make Your cursor as global variable then on your `onDestroy`

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    itemsCursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

And as you are now adding `close` statement as a last statement of `filldata` method, the `Adapter` of `listview` doesn't get any data as `cursor` is already released for that reason you are not getting any data in `listview`.

Comment: I have used the above statement but when i use this my listview doesnt appear on activity. Please mention where should i use that.

Comment: Make your itemsCursor to global and then before closing db close the cursor then all problem will be solved.

Comment: done with this but it doesnt show my listview. I called close in filldata() as last statement.

Comment: done with your new update, all function are going good but that error is appearing in logcat again. But all functioning going smooth.

Answer (score 1):

You should close your `cursor` object and the `database` object in the `onDestroy()` method,

```
if (itemsCursor!=null){
    itemsCursor.close();
}
if (readDatabase!=null){
    readDatabase.close();
}
```

**Edit-**
Have you tried closing the cursor at the end of the fillData() function,

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void fillData() {
    readDatabase.open();
    itemsCursor = readDatabase.fetchAllItems();


    startManagingCursor(itemsCursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseHandler.KEY_ITEM,
            DatabaseHandler.KEY_UNITCOST, DatabaseHandler.KEY_QUANTITY,
            DatabaseHandler.KEY_TOTAL };

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.itemtext, R.id.costtext, R.id.quantitytext,
            R.id.totaltext };

    SimpleCursorAdapter items = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.rowincart, itemsCursor, from, to);

    setListAdapter(items);
    if (itemsCursor!=null){
    itemsCursor.close();
     }
    if (readDatabase!=null){
        readDatabase.close();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Mahajan taking this action make listview disappear.

Comment: @VarunVishnoi Now I would suggest that you should read your code and find out the points where the scope of cursor and database is finished. i.e when you are done with the computations, at that point close your cursor object and the database object. You are creating it for more than one time, so you have to do this for each occurace of both objects.